# Jquery auto complete results appear as individual letters, not words

Tags: php, jquery, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm using jquery to capture a users input in a text field and then display a dropdown of possible options.

The script calls a php page which searches and returns the results to the ajax request.

Where there are multiple values returned by PHP they appear like

```
["Site 4,"Site 2","Site 1","Site 6","Site 7","Site 0"]
```

A single value would appear like

```
["Site 4"]
```

What I get in my drop down is as follows (based on the single entry)

```
[
LINE
"
S
i
t
e
LINE
4
"
]
```

Where LINE is a separator between `Site` &  `4` and the quotes and brackets are shown.

My Jquery is:

```
   $('#site').autocomplete({
    source: function( request, response ) {
        $.ajax({
            url : 'siteCheck.php?name=' + request.term,
            success: function( data ) {
                console.log (data)
                response( $.map( data, function( item ) {
                    return {
                        label: item,
                        value: item,
                        data : item
                    }
                }));
            }
        });
    },
    autoFocus: true,            
    minLength: 1,
        select: function( event, ui ) {
            $('#site').val(ui);
        }               
    });
```

How do I get this to return the dropdown list as

```
Site 4
Site 2
Site 1
Site 6
Site 7
Site 0
```

and not individual letters !

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all: Is it a typo, that your json array has no closing `"` for the first element?

Second: according to the doc for autocomplete, [`source`](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source), would be sufficient to just pass the array as simple array, as you have it already. No need to transform it to something with label/value.

In the example of [remote datasource](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote), they just adding `source: 'remoteScript.php'`

So you could just use

```
$( '#site' ).autocomplete({
    source: 'siteCheck.php?name=' + request.term,
    autoFocus: true, 
    minLength: 1,
    select: function( event, ui ) {
        $('#site').val(ui);
    }
});
```

EDIT:

Try to modify you server side script to accept `term` as GET parameter, then your URL can drop the part, with term added, as the autocomplete does it for you:

```
 source: 'siteCheck.php', //should accept term as parameter
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, yes it was a typo!  I'll try this and let you know how I get on.